# Regex with keycodes javascript

Tags: jquery, regex

I used this regex `[\d\w#,()."\/\-\s]` to allow alphanumeric and `# , . ( ) _ - / "` only.

But when I tried it with keycode it allow `%` and single quotation ( `'` ) why is that?

Here's What I'm trying right now. http://jsfiddle.net/Fn9cy/78/

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply because the keycode for <kbd>%</kbd> is `37`. Just like the left arrow button, which is keycode `37` as well. The virtual keycodes for non ACSII keys overlaps with the ASCII codes.

Comment: what should I do? I need the left arrow to function

Comment: @user3318208 I suppose the simplest solution is to check that there are no modifier keys used when checking for the arrows (since `shift` is always pressed for `%`).

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
(event.keyCode == 37 && key != '%') || (event.keyCode == 39 && key != '\'')
```

Instead of

```
event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39
```

Comment: @if I remove this, in mozilla left arrow not functioning.

Comment: also, if I just only remove event.keyCode == 37 how about the single quotation? -_-

Comment: Then use this `(event.keyCode == 37 && key!='%')` instead of `event.keyCode == 37`

Comment: How about the single quotation?

Comment: Thanks @SajithNair but you have updated my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Add an exception for `keyCode = 37` using `String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode)`

```
if (String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) !== '%' && 
    (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39 || englishAlphabetAndWhiteSpace.test(key)))
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/Fn9cy/80/)

Comment: how about the single quotation?

Comment: @user3318208 as same as for `%` like `String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) !== "'"` check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/Fn9cy/81/)

Comment: the problem is, in mozilla left arrow and right arrow is not working